# how to show the target cell In which an error has occured if you copy and paste onto a validated excel sheet and you get an error message

Tags: excel

0

I have a question. in excel when pasting information into a sheet with validation and allowing the pasted information to follow the rules, so after the user has pasted and I have adjusted the vba code to take account for the pasted information to follow validation rules, I have stumbled upon another problem. say the user pastes large amounts of date that includes many columns and rows (a-z), if there's an error in one of the cells, the popup message will only say "error..." but not show the cell in which the error was found, making it very unfriendly for huge amounts of data. please assist
Share
Edit

I don't know how to edit the vba code for that.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As we don't know your code - how should we be able to help you? Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).